# Какая команда отвечает за прокладку маршрута в google maps?

Tags: google-maps, карты

Какая команда отвечает за прокладку маршрута в `google maps`?
Не могу нагуглить... Дайте ссылку, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нахожусь тут и не могу найти: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#event_removal

Comment: ну как, мой совет помог?.. если - то хорошо бы это зафиксировать, если нет - пишите уточнения в комментариях..

Answer (score 2):

Там не команда, там целая библиотека, для которой нужно подготовить данные, например:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var start = document.getElementById("routefrom");// адрес начальной точки маршрутв
var end = document.getElementById("routeto");// адрес конечной точки маршрута
var request = {origin:start.value, destination:end.value, travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING}; // подготавливаем объект для сервиса маршрутов
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { // если мартшрут получился, то
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0]; // необязательно - локальный объект, из которого можно в дальнейшем вытянуть расстояние по маршруту, плечевые точки и т.д.
  }
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map); // map - глобальная переменная, указывающая на подготовленную карту
```